# Query Database Table with the values of csv in Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv file like this

```
col1,col2,col3
_______________
d1c1,d1c2,d1c3
d2c1,d2c2,d2c3
d3c1,d3c2,d3c3
```

And I have a database table table1 with below schema

```
col1,col4,col5
______________
d1c1,d4c2,d4c3
d2c1,d5c2,d5c3
d4c1,d6c2,d6c3
```

now, I want to query the database table1 with values of `col1` of csv. Is there anyway to do this in nifi?
I can extract the `col1` from csv via QueryRecord processor but unable to route it to any database query processor.

Comment: Did you try `ExecuteSQL`? Please refer this - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following flow worked for me.

**QueryRecord:** for querying the csv file ("Select col1 from FLOWFILE"), don't use "\n" for record separator, use ", ".

**ExtractText** for assigning variable(col.0) for values.

**ExecuteSQL** for doing specific sql query "Select * from table1 where col1 in (${col.0})"

[image]